# How to check the pricing of my Azure Machine learning workspace and registry on Azure Cost Management service

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-cost-calculation

I have an azure subscription and have multiple resource groups. In one of the RG, I have created 2 machine learning workspaces, have trained a few models, ran a few jobs but even after all of it I am unable to see the cost incurred by the operations/resources in Azure Cost Management -> Cost analysis

Tried filtering out the daily cost by service name and was expecting Azure Machine Learning there, but no luck.

[image: Azure Machine learning service name missing here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter based on **resource name instead of service name** in cost analysis to view cost calculated for Azure machine learning resource.

- Using cost analysis, you can view the cost calculated for each resource in a pie chart representation.
  [image]
- I have also tried to filter based on service name and I could not find azure machine learning name in filter.
  [image]
- If you want see the cost calculated for azure machine learning, **select cost by resource option in cost analysis and then resources(preview) option.**
  [image]
- Once selected resources, type machine learning in filter for rows field.
  [image]
  In this way you can check pricing of Azure machine learning.